# Typescript: Unable to get value of the property 'block': object is null or undefined

Tags: typescript, tsc

I write code for valid phone number. But when I compile project I have following mistakes:

1. Unable to get value of the property 'block': object is null or undefined;
2. output from command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc" "C:..\Scripts\MyScripts\TS\BuildPhone.ts" "C:..\Scripts\MyScripts\TS\ProductsViewModel.ts" "C:..\Scripts\MyScripts\TS\helloWorld.ts"" with code 1.

   ```
   // Interface
   interface IPhoneBuild
   {
       showPhone(): string;
       checkPhone(): boolean;
   }

   class Phone
   {
       Code: string;
       Number: string;
       Fax: boolean;
   }

   // Module
   module Phones
   {
       // Class
       export class PhoneBuild implements IPhoneBuild
       {
           private phone: Phone;
           private codes: string[];

           // Constructor
           constructor(public Number: string, public Code: string, public Codes: string[])
           {
               this.phone = this.buildPhone(Number, Code);
               this.codes = Codes;
           }

           //Private Methods
           private clearPhone(public reg: string)
           {
               var re = /\W/g;
               return reg.replace(re, "");
           }

           private buildPhone(public num: string, public code: string)
           {
               var p: Phone = { Code: "", Number: "", Fax: false };

               num = this.clearPhone(num);

               if (num.length == 6)
               {
                   p = { Code: code, Fax: false, Number: num };
               }

               if (num.length == 11)
               {
                   p = { Code: num.substring(0, 4), Fax: false, Number: num.substring(4)};
               }

               return p;
           }

           // Instance member
           public showPhone()
           {
               return this.phone.Code + this.phone.Number;
           }

           public checkPhone()
           {
               return this.phone.Number.length != 7 || this.phone.Code.length == 0;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

What do you think about? I need help.

I found resolve: Delete "public" in properties in methods: buildPhone and clearPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare parameters of a member `function` as public. That is only valid for constructors where it is used as a shorthand for:

- declaring a member variable
- also assigning the input parameter to the member variable

Answer (score 1):

I have given your code a quick tidy.

Where you use `public` or `private` in a constructor, you can avoid the mapping from the parameter to a property on the class as the TypeScript compiler will do it automatically for you.

Your method parameters don't need these access modifiers - they can't be `public` or `private` as they are scoped to the function (i.e. they only live for the duration of the function and cannot be accessed outside of the function).

The example below should compile fine.

```
// Interface
interface IPhoneBuild
{
    showPhone(): string;
    checkPhone(): boolean;
}

class Phone
{
    Code: string;
    Number: string;
    Fax: boolean;
}

// Module
module Phones
{
    // Class
    export class PhoneBuild implements IPhoneBuild
    {
        private phone: Phone;

        // Constructor
        constructor(phoneNumber: string, code: string, public codes: string[])
        {
            this.phone = this.buildPhone(phoneNumber, code);
        }

        //Private Methods
        private clearPhone(reg: string)
        {
            var re = /\W/g;
            return reg.replace(re, "");
        }

        private buildPhone(num: string, code: string)
        {
            var phone: Phone = { Code: "", Number: "", Fax: false };

            num = this.clearPhone(num);

            if (num.length == 6)
            {
                phone.Code = code;
                phone.Number = num;
            }

            if (num.length == 11)
            {
                phone.Code = num.substring(0, 4);
                phone.Number = num.substring(4);
            }

            return phone;
        }

        // Instance member
        public showPhone()
        {
            return this.phone.Code + this.phone.Number;
        }

        public checkPhone()
        {
            return this.phone.Number.length != 7 || this.phone.Code.length == 0;
        }
    }
}
```